# Google Sheets shows very hidden sheets and protected cells when opening an excel file

Tags: excel, google-sheets, vba

I've realised that when google drive converts an excel file to be opened by google sheets, it breaks the veryhidden property and so you can see veryhidden sheets.
The same thing happens with protected cells, showing hidden formulas and logics.

Does anyone know if there is any way to avoid this ? Any effective strategy ?

Comment: The problem is simply that data is never "hidden". You just can tell the system or program to not show it (not for real). But if the program doesn't care about something like "hide that", you can't do anything about it. And Google doesn't care about stuff like "veryhidden sheets" and "hidden formulas"... sorry :(